# Which Joomla version below 2 and near to 1.5. supports PHP 5.4?

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, version, joomla1.5

My web hosting provider  said that they are changing to php 5.4 from  5.2.17  ,and i try to run my site in local with the php 5.4, I got full of issuses

like this

> Strict Standards: Non-static method JError::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in D:\xampp\htdocs\indoor\libraries\joomla\application\application.php on line 721

So I need to upgrade my joomla version which is near to 1.5, presently I am using 1.5.24

Comment: Good on your web host for finally getting up-to-date. PHP 5.2 has been completely unsupported for two years and has known unpatched security holes; it amazes me how many hosting companies are willing to keep it on their servers.

Comment: I had this same problem and then I found this , which broke my heart http://docs.joomla.org/Joomla_1.5_won%27t_work_on_PHP_5.4

Answer (score 2):

Strict standards mode is a PHP setting that tells it to throw warning messages when the code does certain things which are not technically correct.

PHP can, however, cope with these issues -- as per the message in the question, PHP is able to make an assumption about the code in this case and carry on.

These strict mode warnings have always been there; the reason you're getting them in 5.4 and not in 5.2 is because in 5.4 they are enabled by default, whereas in 5.2 they default to being switched off.

Basically, with each new version, PHP is slowly getting stricter about obsolete or poor programming practices. This is generally a good thing, but does leave older code with problems when you upgrade.

But strict mode isn't compulsory; it can be disabled. So if all you're getting are warnings about strict mode, the quickest way to deal with the problem is to switch it off.

You can do this in the `PHP.ini` or `.htaccess` files, or in PHP itself using `ini_set()`.

- PHP.ini: `error_reporting=30719`
- .htaccess: `php_value error_reporting 30719`
- in your PHP code: `error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_STRICT);`

(30719 is eqivalent to `E_ALL` (32767) minus `E_STRICT` (2048), but the names E_ALL and E_STRICT aren't valid in the ini files so you have to use the numeric values)

In general, it would be better to upgrade your system to software that doesn't cause Strict Mode warnings; maybe a newer version of Joomla would help with this. But in the short term this will prevent the strict mode warnings from coming up, and hopefully help you make the transition to the new PHP version.

Hope that helps.

Comment: constants like `E_ALL` and `E_STRICT` are valid in `.ini` files processed by php (so `php.ini` is fine using them), but not in apache-processed ones (so in `.htaccess` or `VirtualHost` configurations you have to use the numeric value. Also, the numeric value may change from one php version to another, so it is always better to check the list of [`predefined constants`](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php)

Answer (score 0):

This is your internal joomla error as your calling a global function statically.Use the debugger and run your page in debug mode.

Comment: Hi Bilal Khalid  , does php 5.4.7 supports  joomla 1.5.24

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is better to upgrade your joomla version now because there is no security updates for joomla 1.5. Also remember that all new extensions developed are in compatible with joomla 2.5 and you can't use it for 1.5.

Answer (score 0):

PHP Strict Standards:

`"Non-static method JTable::getInstance() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context"`

[Source: http://mytecharticle.com/?p=1484](http://mytecharticle.com/?p=1484)